# Работа с threads

Tags: c, многопоточность, pthread

У меня задание в котором надо создать консольную игру в виде перехода дороги, она создана для изучения threads в языке си. Моя цель это создание потока, который бы принимал команды движения с клавиатуры и одновременно должно работать движение воображаемых машинок на экране. 
Я почитал про threads, вроде как понял основную суть, но у меня не получается сделать одновременную работу, при запуске либо одна часть работает либо другая, в чём может быть проблема?

Вид программы в консоли ( x - машинка, @ - игрок ), надо перейти на другую сторону

┌###################################################################┐

```
    X        X                    X  X
                                     X          X
                     X            X
                                  X        XX
           X                             X     X  X
                            X  X           X    X
     X   X                   X  X            X
               X         X
                   X                            X
         X  X

                          @
```

└####################################################################┘

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//Initialize game components
srand(time(0));

screen = initscr();
if(screen == NULL)
    exit(-1);
wresize(screen, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH );
old_cursor = curs_set(0);

froggy.x = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
froggy.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - OUTER_BORDER - 1;

initMotorway();
pthread_t thread;
int status;


status = pthread_create(&thread, NULL,catch_input(), NULL);
if (status != 0) {
    printf("main error: can't create thread, status = %d\n", status);
    exit(10);
}

while(!quit && !error && !player_lost && !player_won)
{

    moveFroggy();
    moveCarsOnMotorway();
    startCar((SCREEN_WIDTH - OUTER_BORDER));
    drawScreen();
    usleep(GAME_SPEED);
}

if(pthread_join(thread, NULL)) {
    printf("main error: can't join the thread");
    exit(11);
}
...
```

Если я ставлю вызов потока

```
status = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, moveFroggy(), NULL);
```

до вызова основных функций с графикой

```
while(!quit && !error && !player_lost && !player_won)
{
    moveCarsOnMotorway();
    startCar((SCREEN_WIDTH - OUTER_BORDER));
    drawScreen();
    usleep(GAME_SPEED);
}
```

То при компиляции появляется пустое окно в терминале и он вроде как считывает команды, хотя в этом я тоже не уверен, так как принты которые я написал в функции MoveFroggy() не отображаются, если же делать наоборот, то отображаются движущиеся машинки но не работает приём команд с клавиатуры.

Листинг MoveFroggy()

```
void moveFroggy(char buf)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
if((first_frogy=false)){
    froggy.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - OUTER_BORDER;
    first_frogy = true;
}
if((checker = true)){
    if((buf == 'a') && (froggy.x > OUTER_BORDER)){
    froggy.x--;
        refresh();
    }
    if(buf == 'd' && (froggy.x < (SCREEN_WIDTH - OUTER_BORDER))){
        froggy.x++;
        refresh();
    }
if (buf == 'w' &&  (froggy.y >= (SCREEN_HEIGHT - NUM_LANES - OUTER_BORDER - GRASS_BORDER)))
    froggy.y--;
if (buf == 's' && (froggy.y < (SCREEN_HEIGHT - OUTER_BORDER)))
    froggy.y++;
if( buf == 'q'){
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
    exit(1);
}
if(froggy.y <= (SCREEN_HEIGHT - NUM_LANES - OUTER_BORDER - GRASS_BORDER))
    player_won = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
}
else{
pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
}
}
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь

UPDATE:

Объявил глобальными варианты и структуры, необходимые для работы программы, снизу написал мьютекс, будет ли он захватывать при вызове все объявленные переменные или только последнюю??

```
// Represents a specific screen positions by Cartesian coordinates
typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

 // Cars on the motorway are organized using a linked list
 // Every list element stores the car's coordinates and a pointer to the next car
typedef struct Car {
    Point position;
    struct Car* next;
} Car;

// List of cars on motorway (pointer to first list element)
Car* motorway;

// Position of froggy on screen
Point froggy;

// Variables to represent current game state
unsigned int error;
unsigned int quit;
unsigned int player_lost;
unsigned int player_won;
bool checker;
bool first_frogy;


// Other global variables
WINDOW* screen;
int old_cursor = 0;
char new_input;
pthread_mutex_t my_mutex;
```

Сделал отдельную функцию, по задумке она должна сохранять input в глобальную переменную, а функция  moveFroggy будет вызываться со всеми функциями отрисовки из потока main, и если был новый input ( проверяется bool переменной ), тогда менять состояние, если нет то проходить мимо

```
void* catch_input(){
char buf;
while((buf = getchar())){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
    new_input = buf;
    checker = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
}
pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Но всё равно при компиляции работает только поток catch_input, а поток main почему то не работает и отрисовка не начинается, если закоментировать поток catch_input, то работает отрисовка
В чём же проблема?

Comment: Вы используете библиотеку ncurses ?

Comment: Да ( ..........)

Comment: настройте обработку функции `getchar()` в не бокируешем режиме

Answer (score 4):

Если предполагать, что один из потоков рассчитывает движение машин, и берет на себя отрисовку, а второй,- принимает команды пользователя, то Вы должны учесть несколько важных вещей :

1. Для обоих ваших потоков существует общий набор данных - это, скажем, массив с текущим положением машин и "пешехода" на карте, если отрисовкой занимается отдельный поток. В приведенном Вами примере, где расчет движения машин и отображение уместились в одном потоке, этими общими данными будет положение пешехода. Эти данные должны быть глобальными. В каждый отдельный момент времени эти данные должны согласованно отображаться на экране.
2. Так как это общие данные, обращения к ним в обоих потоках необходимо синхронизировать с использованием мьютекса. Вы не можете в одном из потоков менять положение пешехода не прибегая к захвату мьютекса, так как второй поток в это время может (или даже должен!) использовать положение пешехода для отображения на экране.

Следовательно мы приходим к такому варианту :

1. В функции потока, который принимает команды пользователя, после ввода хода положение пешехода меняется под мьютексом

   ```
   while((buf=getchar())!='q') {  
       pthread_mutex_lock(my_mutex);  
       if((buf == 'a') && (froggy.x > OUTER_BORDER))  
           froggy.x--;  
       if((froggy.x < (SCREEN_WIDTH - OUTER_BORDER)))  
           froggy.x++;  

       ...  
       pthread_mutex_unlock(my_mutex);  
   }
   ```
2. Либо захватывать этот же мьютекс на время отображения, либо до отображения картинки на экране, под мьютексом скопировать положение пешехода для правильного отображения :

   ```
   ...  
   moveCarsOnMotorway();  
   startCar((SCREEN_WIDTH - OUTER_BORDER));  
   pthread_mutex_lock(my_mutex);  
   temp_froggy = froggy;  
   pthread_mutex_unlock(my_mutex);  
   drawScreen();  
   ...
   ```
3. При отображении отрисовывать сохраненные координаты пешехода.
4. Категорически неверно пытаться из обоих потоков что-то отображать на экране (весь вывод из потока, считывающего команды пользователя нужно убрать), ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет. Лучше при отображении картинки добавить в начало статическую надпись с подсказкой клавиш для ходов.

UPDATE

1. > В связи с этим вопрос, они должны быть исключительно в потоке и не
   >   могут вызываться из main()*?

   Когда вы вызываете main(),- это уже 1 поток. Когда вы создаете внутри еще один функцией pthread_create(), - их уже два, поэтому я и описала два. Соответственно функции отрисовки могут вызываться и из main(), главное, чтобы эти функции отрисовывали уже согласованные со вторым потоком данные (положение пешехода должно быть скопировано под мьютексом и передано в функцию отрисовки, либо вся функция отрисовки, которая использует глобальную переменную с положением пешехода, должна вызываться под мьютексом).
2. > достаточно написать один mutex, и он будет действовать на все
   >   переменные объявленные глобально?

   Мьютексом защищают некоторый общий ресурс, это может быть хоть переменная, хоть десять переменных, массивы или структуры, если они логически связаны. Важно, что если правильно использовать мьютекс, то пока он захвачен одним потоком, другие потоки не могут захватить его, и будут висеть в ожидании, пока мьютекс освободят. В это время поток, захвативший мьютекс должен единолично работать с защищаемыми данными. Тоесть, если есть какие-то общие для потоков данные, их вообще нельзя считывать или изменять, не захватив перед этим мьютекс.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Я в функции изменения состояние не хочу ничего отображать ( эти принты написал для теста, посмотреть работает ли этот поток впринципе ), в нём будет только изменение положения игрока, постараюсь разобраться с mutex. Как я понял мне надо будет реализовать второй поток, в котором будут вызываться функции отрисовки? В связи с этим вопрос, они должны быть исключительно в потоке и не могут вызываться из main() и если да, есть ли какая то разница в синтаксисе между вызовом функции из потока и из main()? или достаточно просто написать стандартный вызов? Спасибо

Comment: И ещё один вопрос, достаточно написать один mutex, и он будет действовать на все переменные объявленные глобально? я правильно это понимаю?

Comment: 1)Вам нужно понять, что когла вы вызываете main(),- это уже 1 поток. Когда вы создаете внутри еще один функцией pthread_create(), - их уже два, поэтому я и описываю два.

Comment: Я изменил листинги в main, создал новую функцию которая бы обрабатывала ввод, и передавала этот ввод в глобальную переменную для дальнейшей обработки в потоке main функцией moveFroggy(), но всё равно не работае, описал проблема в самом низу вопроса

Comment: Это проблема в том что я не правильно работаю в мьютексом или с потоками?

Comment: @AntonBarinov, думаю, проблема в функции getchar(), она блокирует консоль видимо... Надо как-то иначе видимо считывать символы, но пока сходу не могу сказать, чем ее заменить. Теоретически, можно наверно как-то через сигналы от терминала извернуться, надо подумать... Что если попробовать в функции считывания комнанд от пользователя заснуть в select() на дескрипторе стандартного ввода? (поток должен спать, пока не будет введен символ) и после этого читать вимвол из дескриптора ввода через read()? Придется поэксперименторовать...

Comment: Я попробовал закоментировать функцию getchar и оставил там просто printw(), но всё равно не работает, хотя теоретически должна выводится графика

Comment: В библиотеке *ncurses* для того чтобы функция `grtchar()` работала в не блокируещем режиме нужно настроить *ввод* используя функции библиотеки *ncurses* , в часности `nodelay()` или `halfdelay()`

Comment: @AntonBarinov, откуда там printw()? Если вы добавили какой-то вывод в поток считывания от пользователя в цикле, он просто забьет вам всю консоль, и Вы никаких картинок из другого потока не увидите. Вот может то, что Yaroslav предложил, спасет, я с _ncurses_ не работала, но в любом случае нужно сделать ввод от пользователя таким, чтобы он не блокировал консоль.

Comment: printw я добавил исключительно чтобы посмотреть работает ли сама функции из потока, работает, я убрал его.

Comment: @Yaroslav а можно поподробнее про функцию nodelay() , комплиятор требует для неё два атрибуты nodelay(<#WINDOW *#>, <#bool#>)

Comment: @AntonBarinov функция `initscr()` возврашает указатель на ваше основное окно *WINDOW*, а вторая переменая в функции `nodelay()` устанавливается `TRUE` не блокирующий режим  или  `FALSE` блокирующий режим

Comment: @Yaroslav а она должна объявляться до while(getchar) или внутри тела ?

Comment: @AntonBarinov, Мне подсказали, что еще можно ждать ввода с некоторым таймаутом, так поток, считывающий команды пользователя, мог бы блокировать консоль только на незначительное время. Команды : timeout(), halfdelay() и getch(). В случае, если ввода не было, getch() вернет ошибку по истечение таймаута. Как именно этими инструментами пользоваться можете покпать сами.

Answer (score 2):

В даном примере я не описываю работоспособною программу, но показываю логику своей реализации, в упрощеном виде, взаимодействия потоков с использованием библиотеки **ncurses**

В основном потоке функция `main()` происходит работа с библиотекой **ncurses** отрисовка и обработка нажатия клавишь.
Во втором потоке функция `calculate()` происходят все рассчеты.

Для работы с потоками создаем три блока переменых (перемешение по оси X и перемешение по оси Y )

```
int x_1; /*переменые первого потока*/
int y_1; 
int x_2; /*переменые второго потока*/
int y_2;
int x_t; /*переменые проброса*/
int y_t;
```

В начале инициализируем библиотеку **ncurses** и настраиваем основные переменый программы.

```
initscr();
cbreak();  /*убрать режим буфферизации*/
noecho();  /*не выводить набираемые символы */
nodelay(stdsrc,TRUE);  /*сделать не блокирующий режим*/
keypad(stdsrc,TRUE);  /*не обрабатывать служебные клавиши*/
```

инициализируем мьютекс для работы с потоками

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
```

запускаем функцию второго потока

```
 pthread_t thread;
 pthread_create(&thread, NULL,calculate, NULL);
```

в функции `main()` переходим в основной цикл

```
for(;;){
  buf = getchar();
  if(buf != ERR){ /*нажата клавиша*/
    switch(buff){
     .....
     case 'w':  
        y_1++;
        break; 
     ..... 
    }
  }
  /*захватываем мьютекс */
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  /*записываем переменые  */
  y_t = y_1;
  x_1 = x_t;
  /*освобождаем мьютекс*/
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  /*прорисовываем элементы на экране */
  draw_screen(y_1,x_1);
  /*если прорисовка 25 кадров в секунду засыпаем на 40 микросекунд*/
  usleep(40);
}
```

функция рассчета перемещения

```
calculate()
{
   for(;;){

     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
     /*записываем переменые  */
     y_2 = y_t;
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

     /*проводим рассчет перемешения*/
     x_2 = calculate(y_2);

     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
     /*записываем переменые  */
     x_t = x_2;
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   }
   usleep(10);
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том что это программа учебная, и в ней все библиотеки и функции объявдены и сделаны правильно. Моя задача лишь разобраться в потоках, и сделать параллельной работу принятия команды с клавиатуры и отображения графики, и к сожалению в сети не так много информации по потокам

Comment: может имеет смысл запустить каждую отдельную функцию в своём потоке?

Comment: спасибо за ответ, и я нашёл в чём проблема, всё оказалось гораздо проще, надо было просто убрать скобки после имени функции в объявление потока : status = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, moveFroggy, NULL); и всё полшебным образом заработало

Comment: Да простая опечатка , и сразу не заметишь,